# How can I stop zombie pigmen from spawning in some spots in the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need help trying to find out how to get zombie pigmen from spawning in some areas in the nether like caves. I wanna know a quick and easy way to make them spawn where I want them to spawn in survival mode.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can try to stop [Zombie Pigmen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Pigmen) from spawning in the nether by breaking their spawn rules:

1. Place half-slabs on every spot you do not want them to spawn on.
2. Replace the [Netherrack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Netherrack) or [Soul Sand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Soul_Sand) with glass, or any transparent material.*
3. Make sure everything is 1-block high. *(Though it'll then be nearly impossible to treverse around).*

You can't do anything regarding light levels as Zombie Pigmen spawn in any light condition.

*You can do this to the surrounding area of an overworld portal to prevent them from spawning there.

Answer (score 1):

Trapdoors on the tops of rooms also prevents them from spawning and still allowing travel.